# How to pipe stdout to external app, internally within my code? C

Tags: c, client, client-server, pipe, stdout

I've currently written a udp client, which simply listens on specified port, for packets destined to a specific multicast group.

at the end, i'm printing the input to stdout in the following manner:

```
write(STDOUT_FILENO, buffer, num_of_bytes);
```

And executing the program in the following manner:

```
./udp_listen 224.10.10.10 4567 | mpg321 -
```

That way all output is piped to mpg321 app, which plays the stream of bytes as music.

The above implementation, is of course making me kind of "lose control" over my program, as it opens mpg321 app and plays.
I want to avoid this, and in someway, pipe the **write(....)** into mpg321, directly within my program.

How can one achieve this? I'm coding in C.

Thank you.

Comment: You could start a process of `mpg321` in your application and write to its `stdin`?

Comment: You can use either `popen` or `fork`+`dup2`+`exec`

Comment: @LukePark , that's what i want to do - but don't know how to do it.

kaylum - i'll have a look in those, care to share a little bit more of info? :) much appreciated.

Thanks guys

Comment: Greetings. It's hard to tell what you're asking for... What parts of the relevant manuals are you having troubles understanding?

Comment: @Adiel I was hoping the pointers would prompt you to read the man pages and work it out from there. Start with `popen`. That will run the command for you (`mpg321` in this case) and give you a stream to read from or write to. Writes to the stream will end up in the command's `stdin` which is exactly what you asked for (I think).

Comment: Using [`popen()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/popen.html) is very straight-forward.  In your UDP listener, instead of writing to `stdout`, you'll write to the file stream returned by `popen()` — using standard I/O functions.  Or, if you do it yourself, you'll write to the write end of the pipe that you create; the child process will sort its plumbing out so that the read end of the pipe becomes its standard input before executing `mpg321` (remembering to close both ends of the pipe as created).

Comment: Hey guys, thank you very much.

i'll go over the relevant man's this evening.

@kaylum, according to what you said about popen, it seems that i need only that - get a stream representing mpg321 process, which i can write to. 

If that's the case - why would i need the other commands you mentioned?

Thanks !

Comment: @Adiel `popen` essentially does the other sequence for you. And in your case that is sufficient. But the other technique is also useful to learn for other situations where you may need more control than `popen` gives you. For example, `popen` only gives you a unidirectional pipe (read or write). You may want to change both the command's `stdout` and `stdin` which cannot be done with `popen`. Another example is if you want to connect the command's `stdin` to a file instead of explicitly making `write` calls. In that case also, the latter sequence is more appropriate.

Comment: @kaylum, thank you for the elaborating answers.
i've used peopen for the time being, and it worked flawlessly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @kaylum for providing the answer i was looking for.

i've used **popen** with the command to initiate mpg321 , with redirecting its stderr output to a file.

After that i've used fileno() method to get the file descriptor number,
to be used with write() calls.

Worked great.

Thanks